# Custom module 'managed_file' variable info keeps disappearing

Tags: files

I have a custom module which allows a 'managed_file' upload in the settings/config page. This works fine and displays as expected after uploading (with the filename linked, and a "Remove" submit button) but the value of the field keeps disappearing after some time. What am I missing?

Here's the code from the custom module:

```
  $form['custom_managed_jpg'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#name' => 'custom_managed_jpg',
    '#title' => 'Custom Image (JPG)',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('custom_managed_jpg', ''),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://custom_directory/',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg'),
    ),
    '#description' => t('This is a custom image (jpg format).'),
  );
```

It appears to be a problem with the file_load function. The variable is indeed saved, as I get a file ID when I `dpm()` the `variable_get('custom_managed_jpg')` (a number -- the `fid`). However, when I `dpm()` the result of `file_load($fid)` it is empty.

The strangest part is that this works as expected to start with, and the file will even remain between page loads and cache clears, but then after a few hours it just disappears as described above without any warning.

**UPDATE:**

It seems that the reason `file_load` doesn't return anything is that the directory (`public://custom_directory/`) is empty. At some point these files are being deleted from the directory but I have no idea why.

**UPDATE2:**

When I watch the `file_managed` table, I can see a new file added after uploading. The one difference between files uploaded here and those already in the table is that the `status` field is set to 0 instead of 1. I am guessing that could be part of the problem? How/where do I set the status to 1 programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott's code is right (and is nearly identical to what I had) but the final step I was missing is in the form's submit handler, where I needed to grab the file that was uploaded and mark it as permanent, and add a [file usage](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_usage_add/7) to tell Drupal the file was in use. By default Drupal treats uploaded files as temporary and they are deleted from the database and filesystem after 6 hours (when cron runs).

Here's the submit handler code.

```
function MODULE_admin_settings_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  if (isset($form_state['values']['custom_managed_jpg']) && $form_state['values']['custom_managed_jpg']!="") {
    // Load the file via file.fid.
    $file = file_load($form_state['values']['custom_managed_jpg']);
    // Change status to permanent.
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($file);
    // Record that the module (in this example, "custom module") is using the file. 
    file_usage_add($file, 'custom_module', 'custom_managed_jpg', $user->uid); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Drupal 4.7 this will not work for you (hook_settings is from Drupal 4.7).

Set up the menu item:

```
function MODULE_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/config/PATH'] = array(
    'title'             => 'TITLE',
    'description'       => 'DESCRIPTION',
    'page callback'     => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments'    => array('MODULE_admin_settings'),
    'access callback'   => 'user_access',
    'access arguments'  => array('administer site configuration'),
  );

  return $items;
}
```

Page Callback Function must return `system_settings_form($form)`:

```
function MODULE_admin_settings() {
  $form['fieldset_homepage']['custom_managed_jpg'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#name' => 'custom_managed_jpg',
    '#title' => 'Custom Image (JPG)',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('custom_managed_jpg', ''),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://custom_directory/',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg'),
    ),
    '#description' => t('This is a custom image (jpg format).'),
  );

  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

`system_settings_form` will save all form fields to the variable table and I think is the part you are missing.

Comment: Thanks, I misspoke RE: hook_settings! Actually the full code I have looks a lot like this but it just seems like the file disappears from the settings after a while. I guess I need to do further troubleshooting. Will post back with any other relevant info.

Comment: I've updated my question.